# deleted select photos previously synced to my phone but not the whole folder

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

How can I delete select photos from my iphone 8 that were previously synced from my computer but I can't find the folder on my computer, a microsoft tech guy helped me get photos from the Microsoft photos opp onto my phone after I dropped my iphone 7 and couldn't get the pics off of it.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) At present your question really isn't clear. If I read between the lines, are you asking how it is you can delete *some* photos from your iPhone that were not taken on your iPhone, but which were transferred to your iPhone from your computer? So the end result would be that you currently have a number of photos you want to keep, but also a number of photos you want to delete and you want to know how to delete those photos? If so, where are the photos located (camera roll, album, etc)? Please edit your question to clarify what you're asking, so we can help.

Comment: I’ve added many answer, but am not certain I’m addressing things. Please edit the question if we’re off the mark!

Answer (score 1):

I would turn on iCloud sync of photos so you can use a computer to ohotos to be deleted or just delete them from a larger screen.

For me, using a computer via photos is even better, but you might not have a Mac but just about everyone can borrow a computer to organize things easier than tapping on an iPhone.